# Upon importing spacy, I found TypeError

Tags: python, import, spacy

Libraries are installed - not sure why this is throwing an error.

It works on one of my rigs with the same platform - ubuntu 19.10 - python3.8 and the associated libraries in a virtualenv.

I'm going to show you what I see:

Here's im trying to validate spacy -- which fails.

```py
(p3env) gordon@citadel:~/p3env/alice/alice/spiders$ python -m spacy validate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from thinc.neural.util import prefer_gpu, require_gpu
  File "/home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/thinc/neural/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ._classes.model import Model  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/thinc/neural/_classes/model.py", line 7, in <module>
    import srsly
  File "/home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/srsly/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ._pickle_api import pickle_dumps, pickle_loads
  File "/home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/srsly/_pickle_api.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import cloudpickle
  File "/home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/srsly/cloudpickle/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .cloudpickle import *
  File "/home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/srsly/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 167, in <module>
    _cell_set_template_code = _make_cell_set_template_code()
  File "/home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/srsly/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 148, in _make_cell_set_template_code
    return types.CodeType(
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
(p3env) gordon@citadel:~/p3env/alice/alice/spiders$ ^C
```

So I just try to install some of those libraries which turn out to be present. - I know everything I need is installed --

```py
(p3env) gordon@citadel:~/p3env/alice/alice/spiders$ pip install thinc
Requirement already satisfied: thinc in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (7.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from thinc) (0.9.6)
Requirement already satisfied: murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from thinc) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from thinc) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.0 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from thinc) (1.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: blis<0.5.0,>=0.4.0 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from thinc) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from thinc) (0.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from thinc) (4.36.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from thinc) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: preshed<3.1.0,>=1.0.1 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from thinc) (3.0.2)
(p3env) gordon@citadel:~/p3env/alice/alice/spiders$ pip install cloudpickle
Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.2.2)
(p3env) gordon@citadel:~/p3env/alice/alice/spiders$ pip install srsly
Requirement already satisfied: srsly in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.1.0)
(p3env) gordon@citadel:~/p3env/alice/alice/spiders$ pip install spacy
Requirement already satisfied: spacy in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (3.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.0 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (1.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: blis<0.5.0,>=0.4.0 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: srsly<1.1.0,>=0.1.0 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (0.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: thinc<7.2.0,>=7.1.1 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (7.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.2.0 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (0.9.6)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy) (1.25.6)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy) (2019.9.11)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from thinc<7.2.0,>=7.1.1->spacy) (4.36.1)
(p3env) gordon@citadel:~/p3env/alice/alice/spiders$ pip uninstall spacy
Uninstalling spacy-2.2.1:
  Would remove:
    /home/gordon/p3env/bin/spacy
    /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bin/*
    /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy-2.2.1.dist-info/*
    /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled spacy-2.2.1
(p3env) gordon@citadel:~/p3env/alice/alice/spiders$ pip install spacy
Processing /home/gordon/snap/code/common/.cache/pip/wheels/1d/22/2b/2d5d8fe5e5fe728a766158a89d017051c19005bb7aabc1d79a/spacy-2.2.1-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: blis<0.5.0,>=0.4.0 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (3.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: srsly<1.1.0,>=0.1.0 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (0.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (0.9.6)
Requirement already satisfied: thinc<7.2.0,>=7.1.1 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (7.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.2.0 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.0 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (1.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy) (2019.9.11)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy) (1.25.6)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0 in /home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from thinc<7.2.0,>=7.1.1->spacy) (4.36.1)
Installing collected packages: spacy
Successfully installed spacy-2.2.1
```

RIGHT HERE -- I just try importing spacy and this is what I'm getting on one of the machines... while the other works -- odd I'll need to look into this -

Has anyone run into this ?

```py
(p3env) gordon@citadel:~/p3env/alice/alice/spiders$ python
Python 3.8.0 (default, Oct 15 2019, 09:10:20) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20191008] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import spacy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from thinc.neural.util import prefer_gpu, require_gpu
  File "/home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/thinc/neural/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ._classes.model import Model  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/thinc/neural/_classes/model.py", line 7, in <module>
    import srsly
  File "/home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/srsly/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ._pickle_api import pickle_dumps, pickle_loads
  File "/home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/srsly/_pickle_api.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import cloudpickle
  File "/home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/srsly/cloudpickle/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .cloudpickle import *
  File "/home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/srsly/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 167, in <module>
    _cell_set_template_code = _make_cell_set_template_code()
  File "/home/gordon/p3env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/srsly/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 148, in _make_cell_set_template_code
    return types.CodeType(
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes
```

I don't believe this happens outside of the virtualenv.

Let me know if you have seen this one, when I fix it I'll update the post.

Comment: It might be a Python 3.8 issue with cloudpickle. Take a look at this: https://bugs.python.org/issue36886. Try a virtual env with Python 3.7.

Comment: See https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/4975

Answer (score 0):

```
$ python3.8 -m pip install srsly --upgrade
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting srsly
  Downloading srsly-2.0.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (311 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 311 kB 1.3 MB/s 
ERROR: thinc 7.3.1 has requirement srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6, but you'll have srsly 2.0.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: spacy 2.2.3 has requirement srsly<1.1.0,>=0.1.0, but you'll have srsly 2.0.0 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: srsly
  Attempting uninstall: srsly
    Found existing installation: srsly 0.1.0
    Uninstalling srsly-0.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled srsly-0.1.0
Successfully installed srsly-2.0.0
```

You might want to use `python3.8 -m pip install srsly==1.0.1`.