# Spacy add_alias, TypeError

Tags: python, cython, spacy, spacy-3

**MWE**

```
from spacy.kb import KnowledgeBase
import spacy 


#kb.add_entity already called.
nlp = spacy.blank("en")
kb = KnowledgeBase(vocab=nlp.vocab, entity_vector_length=96)
name = "test"
qid = 1 # type(qid) => int
kb.add_alias(alias=name.lower(), entities=[qid], probabilities=[1])
```

produces the error at the last line: `TypeError: an integer is required`

A [previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58577977/upon-importing-spacy-i-found-typeerror) suggested that the same error arose in another context (importing SpaCy) because the version of `srsly` was greater than 2. Using their solution of downgrading to `v1.0.1` of `srsly` merely switched the error to module `srsly` has no attribute `read_yaml`.

I am using `spacy 3.4.4` and `srsly 2.4.5`.

**Update**
A fuller stack trace points to line 228 in `spacy/kb.pyx`:

```
  for entity, prob in zip(entities, probabilities):
            entity_hash = self.vocab.strings[entity] #this gives the error
            if not entity_hash in self._entry_index:
                raise ValueError(Errors.E134.format(entity=entity))

            entry_index = <int64_t>self._entry_index.get(entity_hash)
            entry_indices.push_back(int(entry_index))
            probs.push_back(float(prob))
```

Comment: The advice on downgrading srsly is from 2019, that's not going to be relevant here.

Comment: Yes, it didn't solve the error. I re-upgraded when downgrading didn't solve the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug. In the API docs `KnowledgeBase.add_alias` has type `Iterable[Union[str, int]]` for `entities` but the code above (the actual error is actually one line below) only works for `str` and not `int` values. (The marked line should have `self.vocab.strings.as_int(entity)`.)

That said, the value `1` is probably not going to be the right value here no matter what and the simplest solution is to use strings instead like `"1"` or `"Q1"`, which should currently work as expected. You also need to add the entity before adding aliases (this snippet is not going to work even with a string value).

Comment: The error was that I was using `1`, not `"1"`. The first snippet assumes that the entities have already been added.